# How do I delete files using PowerShell that DON'T include a certain name?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to delete all video file copies in my video folder, I used Adobe Media Encoder to make all my videos a smaller size so that they don't take up as much storage on my PC. I want to delete the files that were previously there. I have tried multiple different articles/StackOverflow forums of doing so but they're either too complicated and not copy/pasteable or they don't do what I want them to do (Deleting files that DON'T include '_1.mp4').

I am trying to use this command:

`Remove-Item -Path E:\Desktop\test\tester\* -force -Include '*_1.mp4'`

The problem is, I want it to NOT delete the ones that include '_1.mp4', I want it to instead delete the ones that do not include it. Is that possible, and if so, how would I do that?

Comment: See this example: [use the **Include** and **Exclude** parameters to specify the files to delete.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Remove-Item?view=powershell-7.3&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-5.0#example-2-delete-document-files-in-a-folder)

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem. Is there also a way to remove the "_1" part after I've deleted the old files so my file names look good?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\Desktop\test\tester' -Filter '*_1.*' -File | Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}{1}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace '.{2}$'), $_.Extension }`. If the files can also be found inside subfolders, add `-Recurse` after the `-File` switch